# How Can I create a PDF background which is not printed (by default)?

Tags: pdf, backgrounds, adobe

I'm looking for a solution to include a PDF background layer, which is not printed by default. I've seen that adobe seems to support a *watermark* layer, as discussed on [graphicdesign.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13922/how-to-create-a-pdf-which-has-a-background-that-does-not-print). I cannot test this method because I don't have access to these tools.

However, my understanding of a *watermark* is that it superimposed on the PDF document, whereas I want to have non printable background. I've tried `\pagecolor`, but it was printed using *Adobe Acrobat* on *Windows*.

I can always manually remove the background myself, but I want that a regular user who just prints my document doesn't print anything from the background. I'm assuming here that this user is using the bloated *Acroread* (aka *Acrobat*) PDF reader.

A [related thread](http://forums.serif.com/showthread.php?t=107282) also links an [example PDF](http://www.mdcodewizard.com/CMS1500/CMS1500-MDCW.pdf) which has a non-printable layer.

Here's MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{minimal}                                                   
\usepackage{xcolor}                                               
\definecolor{testcol}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}                                      
\begin{document}                                                            
\pagecolor{testcol}                                                         
test                                                                        
\end{document}
```

I'm collecting tools and operating systems where the `ocg-p` method works (see examples in accepted answer). Please `edit` the question if you have experimented with a PDF viewer not listed.

#### Known to work

- *Adobe Reader* 11.0.3, Windows: Layer visible on screen/printed: yes/no

#### Incomplete tests

- *Zathura* 0.2.9-1 with *mupdf* backend, Linux: Layer visible/printed: yes/yes (rather: **no/no**)
  (Zathura does not support toggling visibility of individual layers. It displays + prints always *all* layers, whatever their setting regarding visibility + printability. This should better be described as ***'no support for layers at all'***. Tested with Zathura 0.3.7-1.)
- *Evince* 3.12.1 (poppler backend 0.26.2-1 ), Linux: Layer visible/printed: yes/yes
  (Tested with Evince 3.22.1 / poppler backend 0.48.0. Layers may be individually toggled on/off for visibility. Evince prints all layers which are currently toggled as 'on'. Evince supports layer marking asking for 'never' to be printed.)
- *Preview.app*, Mac: Layers visible/printed: yes/yes (rather: **no/no**)
  (Preview.app does not support toggling visibility of individual layers. It displays + prints always *all* layers, whatever their setting regarding visibility + printability. This should better be described as ***'no support for layers at all'***. Tested with Preview.app v9.0 (909.18) on macOS Sierra 10.12.6)

Comment: This could be done using Optional Content Groups (OCG), but support is sporadic at best across the wide range of PDF viewers. Several packages are of interest: http://ctan.org/ctan-portal/search/?phrase=ocg

Comment: it seems all of them are based on *Asymptote*. Coincidence?

Comment: `ocg-p` seems interesting and adds important information: *OCGs are part of the PDF specification since version 1.5*, *OCGs are not part of the ISO standard 19005 PDF/A-1, but part of the newer
PDF/A-2 standard*.

Comment: @Kurt You, in your edit, say: Evince supports layer marking asking for 'never' to be printed. Does this mean that Evince follows the PDF spec in this regard finally? This would be good news, making `ocgcolorlinks` (pkg `ocgx2`) functional.

Comment: @AlexG: I will re-test it as soon as I have an opportunity...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of *Paul Gessler*, I found `ocg-p`, which does exactly what I need. Here is a demonstration of an unprintable colorbox:

```
\documentclass[]{minimal}
\usepackage{ocg-p}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{testcol}{cmyk}{0,0,0.5,0}
\begin{document}
regular text
% \begin{ocg}{layer name}{layer id}{initial visibility}
\begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{Background}{1}{1}
  \colorbox{testcol}{text on Background layer}
\end{ocg}
regular text
\end{document}
```

I'm coping the explanation of the options from the manual:

[image: manual screenshot]

Indeed the text and the colorbox were not printed using standard Adobe Reader settings, but it was visible on the computer screen. Adobe Reader Version 11.0.3.

[image: worked]

On the topic of non-printable backgrounds, I found the following solution (compile thrice):

```
\documentclass[]{article}                                                   
\usepackage{ocg-p}                                                          
\usepackage{background}                                                     
\usepackage{xcolor}                                                         

\definecolor{testcol}{cmyk}{0,0,0.5,0}                                      
\backgroundsetup{%                                                          
scale=1,%                                                                   
angle=0,%                                                                   
opacity=1,%                                                                 
contents={%                                                                 
% \begin{ocg}{layer name}{layer id}{initial visibility}                     
\begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{Background}{1}{1}%                              
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%     
   \path [fill=green!30] (current page.south west)rectangle (current page.north east);%
  \end{tikzpicture}%      
\end{ocg}}%                        
}                                                                           
\begin{document}                                                            
regular text                                                                
% \begin{ocg}{layer name}{layer id}{initial visibility}                     
\begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{Background}{1}{1}                               
  \colorbox{testcol}{text on Background layer}                              
\end{ocg}                                                                   
regular text                                                                
\end{document}
```

Comment: Pretty solid answer no need for CW. I'll ping the mods.